# Bash function behaves differently in script than when entered manually on command line, why?

Tags: bash, function, syntax

running - ./bashfile.sh a 1 1

```
#!/bin/bash

addit () {
echo $(($2 + $3))
}

if [ $1 == a ]
then
addit
fi
```

produces

```
syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+ ")
```

What is causing this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You should call your `addit` function in the script, something like: `addit $1 $2`, after the definition of `addit`.

Comment: You are not calling the function...

Comment: In my haste I neglected that the function is called inside of an if statement. I have added it now, sorry.

Comment: The parameters that `addit` see are those you pass to the function, not those that are passed to the script. Call `addit` with `$2` and `$3` as I show you in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call your `addit` function in the script, something like: `addit $1 $2`, after the definition of `addit`.

```
#!/bin/bash
addit () {
    echo $(($1 + $2))
}

addit $1 $2
```

Running:

```
chmod +x bashfile.sh
./bashfile 1 1
2
```